# How to debug Angular JS code that is run without a browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, qt, nginx

I have an app written in Qt and via a mechanism that I am not really clear on some Angular JS code gets run when requests are sent to certain URLs. I think it happens via some nginx and routeProvider magic. How can I debug that Angular code? There's no browser involved so I can't use the standard tools I would use there. Even just printing some variable and/or process state would help, but how can I do that in this scenario?

Comment: Use some IDE like webstrom or github atom in such cases, they would be helpful.

Comment: With Webstorm how would I do this? I have a Mac executable in one dir and some Angular code in another that somehow get invoked. I tried pointing Webstorm at the C++ dir but it doesn't seem to know what to do with it. And isn't Atom an editor?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for anyone searching for the same thing.

Qt has a QWebInspector class that give you all the familiar tools you'd get using the Chrome web developer tools. It was very easy to use. I did this:

```
  ui->webView->setUrl(url); 
  QWebPage *page = ui->webView->page();
  page->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled, true);
  QWebInspector *inspector = new QWebInspector();
  inspector->setPage(page);
  inspector->show();
```

And this gave me an error console, JS debugger, and other goodies.